# JS method is returning the value as undefined after assignment in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

Here is the snippet of my code

```
@track alltraffic = [];

//using wire method to call a method to load all values while page load
@wire(getAllTraffic) alltraffic;

//calling different method with parameters imperatively and assigning to 
 alltraffic
 onDateChange(event){
 this.weekend = event.target.value;


getSpecificTraffic({divId: this.divisionvalue, communityId: 
                     this.communityvalue, week: this.weekend})
    .then(result => {
    console.log('result'+JSON.stringify(result));  
    this.alltraffic = [...result].map(record => {return record});   

    })           
    .catch(error => {
        this.error = error;
        console.log(error);
    });  
  }
```

when i do JSON.Stringify, i get the result in console.log but i wanted that as data format, so i can show that in my table.

i get the table value in the wire method, but i am calling another method imperatively that updates the same JS variable to display the data, but i am not getting it as data. I get as [object Object] and if i stringfy it is in JSON format. How can i get it as data.

in the wire method i am using alltraffic and use alltraffic.data in the html.

here is my HTML code

```
<template if:true={alltraffic.data}>   
   <tbody >
         <template for:each={alltraffic.data} for:item="traffic">
         <tr>
           <td>
              <div class="slds-truncate"> {traffic.trafficType} </div>
           </td>
         </tr>
    </tbody>
 </template>
```

lightning-web-components

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieving results by calling Apex imperatively from LWC. Getting results on JSON.Stringify but not sure how to load this data](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/287894/retrieving-results-by-calling-apex-imperatively-from-lwc-getting-results-on-jso)

Comment: It looks like this is the same as your previous question, which was closed for not being very clear about what your actual issue is (and what piece of code is causing the issue). Asking the same question multiple times, and not making any changes, is probably going to lead to the same result (and, eventually, being barred by the stackexchange system itself from asking any more questions).

Comment: If you can [edit] your question, or maybe just restructure what you have now, to be more clear about what the problem is and provide a Minimum Viable Reproduction, you might be able to save this question from being closed.

Comment: @DerekF I have explained everything in the question. . Middle portion of the question has all the explanation. The other one was closed, so i have to ask again because i am not able to resolve the issue. Issue is mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you parse it back into an object JavaScript reads it as primitive object again

```
let data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks